# Would epigenetics matter in cloning via human transmutation?

Tags: biology, magic, creature-design, humans

A character of mine (let’s call them A) is basically a ghost possessing someone else’s (B’s) body, but neither of them like sharing with each other. As they live in a world where magic is a thing, they’ve decided to pull a *Fullmetal Alchemist* and transmute a body for A to move into like the characters in Arakawa’s story tried (and failed) to do for their mother. **Would it make sense for A’s new body to be exactly the same as B’s, or would it be similar but not exact** due to it being put together based on B’s genome but not having the experiences that B had (like how much B ate or slept or got sick as a kid)**?**

Comment: I think there is information missing - what can magic *do*? How does it work? What's reasonable or not relies heavily on that. The question seems to suggest that magic can create a fully grown human body. Maybe not instantly but less than the time it would take for a clone to be *born* and age naturally to the same state. So, given that, it doesn't seem implausible that the cloned body would take the same shape as the original, regardless that it didn't have the same experience.

Comment: I know of transmuting lead to gold regular alchemist style, and transmogrification of children into monsters Calvin & Hobbes style but I am less sure about transmutation of bodies.  For those us unfamiliar with transmutation as pertains to bodies, maybe you could unpack what that means in your world.

Comment: I mentioned Fullmetal Alchemist specifically as the alchemy in that series is pretty close to the kind of magic that I’m planning on using: anyone can use it so long as they learn the theory behind it and have materials to transmute. I’m not planning on there being a “gate” like in FMA, but rather the magician being limited based on the amount of energy they can use.

Comment: Not everybody knows what Fullmetal Alchemist implies. Thus, better explain it

Comment: Been a while since I saw FMA - I recall transmuting biological things was very seldom done. It *was* a thing but just not shown as much. Still, given how it worked in the anime, I don't see why you wouldn't be able to make a perfect 1:1 copy of another person. Well, maybe around 98% to account for imperfect skill but transmutation could achieve basically anything, as long as it involved *change*.

Comment: *"Pull a full metal alchemist"?* Pull them from where? Why would pulling an alchemist (fully metallic or not) have anything to do with *"transmuting"* a human body? What do you mean by "transmuting" a body? Transmute it into gold? VTC as eminently unclear.

Comment: When I said “pull a Fullmetal Alchemist” I was referring to the story by Arakawa wherein two boys attempt to make a.k.a. transmute a new body for their deathly ill and actively dying mother to use (and failed to do so in time, which led to the plot of the story). To “pull a Fullmetal Alchemist” in this context is a colloquialism that means to “do the same as in the story Fullmetal Alchemist” and try to make a human body via alchemy

Comment: @NottheletterA I was under the impression that they didn't make a new body, they tried to resurrect her. Which is a big no-no in FMA world. But there were biologist alchemists like Tucker (ha-ha, I know) and that doctor Marco from later in the series. There were probably others but can't remember names. There definitely were doctors who were alchemists but shown few and far between. Given how alchemy was defined, it seems perfectly possible to shape any body you want with it. However, in-universe the practice has been banned because it is quite dangerous.

Comment: @VLAZ I know that she died (thus the “failed to do so in time”), but I thought they had started trying before she had actually died? I will admit that it’s been a while since I’ve seen it too, so I could definitely be wrong... As for “any shape you want” wouldn’t that require a deeper knowledge of genetics than just copying the genome?

Comment: @NottheletterA probably. But that's basically all alchemy anyway - it seems to require knowledge of the subject as well as knowledge of just magic.

Comment: I'm voting to leave this question open. I think the magic aspect is a red herring; there seems to be a very legitimate question here, which is, if I clone an organism, how closely will the clone, after X time of physical maturation, resemble the original as of the same X time?

Comment: @Matthew so, you think it's irrelevant to add "but my magic can also manipulate the traits of the body"?

Comment: @VLAZ, okay, I'll grant that the question as worded isn't ideal; "does it make sense ... because magic" is almost always going to be "yes". However, I don't see a way to give a sensible answer without considering first the extent to which a cloned body could differ due to environmental factors. Once that is understood, "magic" can be used to hand-wave to a desired location within that spectrum of possibilities. So, yes, I do in fact think "magic" is irrelevant to the question that actually needs to be answered here.

Answer (score 5):

## Different bodies

You can get some of the way to answering your question by looking at identical twins. Check out "[Why Are Identical Twins Different?](https://www.verywellfamily.com/why-are-identical-twins-different-2447125)" and "[Why Identical Twins Don't Always Look the Same](https://www.kqed.org/futureofyou/134603/why-identical-twins-dont-always-look-the-same)" for more detail.

In reality, you'd see more differences than identical twins because the new body will not have been raised in the same environment as the first body. Environment has a huge impact on our bodies. For example, genetics only accounts for [80% of height](https://medlineplus.gov/genetics/understanding/traits/height/#:%7E:text=Scientists%20estimate%20that%20about%2080,height%20are%20only%20partially%20understood.) and between [25% and 80%](https://www.health.harvard.edu/staying-healthy/why-people-become-overweight#:%7E:text=Genetic%20influences&text=The%20strength%20of%20the%20genetic,as%2070%25%20to%2080%25.) of proclivity for overweight. And that's to say nothing of wear and tear, injuries, etc.